# trying to dynamically replace the url from "a href" but javascript is not updating results

Tags: javascript, html, url, href

I'm trying to replace the urls in the html using javascript but it is not working although when I test it by I "alerting" them the values pop up correctly, but when I publish it and click on the images the new urls are not applied. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Could you please look at the code and tell me what is going on?:

```
<script>
    var rutaBase = "assets/fotos/";

    function cambieFotos(cualFoto) {
        var listaFotos = ["360.jpg", "foto3.jpg", "mathura.jpg"];
        var numFotosLista = listaFotos.length;
        var foto1 = document.getElementById("foto1");
        var foto2 = document.getElementById("foto2");
        var foto3 = document.getElementById("foto3");

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var fotoAleatoria = listaFotos[Math.floor(Math.random() * numFotosLista)];
            var fotoRoll = document.getElementById("foto" + (i + 1));
            fotoRoll.src = "assets/fotos/" + fotoAleatoria;
            fotoRoll.href = "assets/fotos/" + fotoAleatoria; //this code is not working.

            var sacarFotoLista = listaFotos.indexOf(fotoAleatoria);
            listaFotos.splice(sacarFotoLista, 1);
            numFotosLista = listaFotos.length;
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="contenedor">
    <a href="#"><img id="foto1" onMouseOver="cambieFotos(this)" src="assets/fotos/360.jpg"></a> <--!this needs to update-->
    <a href="#"><img id="foto2" onMouseOver="cambieFotos(this)" src="assets/fotos/foto3.JPG"></a><--!this needs to update-->
    <a href="#"><img id="foto3" onMouseOver="cambieFotos(this)" src="assets/fotos/mathura.jpg"></a><--!this needs to update-->
</div>
<!--contenedor-->
```

Answer (score 2):

fotoRoll is an `<img>`, not the surrounding `<a>`. You should modify the parent instead:

```
fotoRoll.parentNode.href="assets/fotos/"+fotoAleatoria;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the href on the image element, not the hyperlink element. Try something like

```
fotoRoll.parentNode.href="assets/fotos/"+fotoAleatoria;
```

Comment: @irrelephant got there first